# ssis package using email task to attach excel file

Tags: excel, ssis, email-attachments

i have an SSIS package that generates an Excel file `(.xls)` and then have an email task to attach this file and email it. my issue is when it gets emailed the attachment is showing as a `.xlsx.html` file and i cannot open it. do i need to do something else before attaching?

Comment: How are you attaching the file in the task editor? I'd suggest an expression with the file path to the file you just created.

Comment: @KeithL yes within the 'send mail task editor' under Mail > attachments. managed to fix it - for some reason I had the file location entered twice